# python: list of lists to ordered dict and group by first element

Tags: performance, list, list-comprehension, ordereddictionary

I have a list of lists `list1 = [['colour','red'],['colour','blue],['shape','rect'],['shape','square']]`

what is the fastest way to make an OrderedDict out of list1?

```
{colour:['red','blue'],shape:['rect','square']}
```

So far, I have been able to map through list1 and extract unique elements in index 0 of each inner list and return it as list2.

I could map through list1 and list2 and if maching element found then take element at index 1 from each inner list of list1 but I am not sure if it is right approach / fast approach.

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches, depending on your inputs:

Option 1: If, as in your example, all the matched keys are consecutive (so you always see all `colours` together), you can use `itertools.groupby` to group them:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

list1 = [['colour','red'],['colour','blue],['shape','rect'],['shape','square']]
dict1 = OrderedDict((k, [v for _, v in grp]) for k, grp in groupby(list1, itemgetter(0)))
```

This is, at least theoretically, the fastest approach, since it writes each key in the `dict` exactly once without looking them up repeatedly each time a key is seen, but it relies on the input being ordered by key.

Option 2: Use the `__missing__` special method to make an `OrderedDict` with the same behavior on looking up a missing key as `defaultdict(list)` (sadly, the two types are incompatible, so you can't make a class that inherits from both and call it a day), then write an explicit loop to fill it in:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class OrderedMultidict(OrderedDict):
    __slots__ = ()  # Avoid overhead of per-instance __dict__
    def __missing__(self, key):
        # Missing keys are seamlessly initialized to an empty list
        self[key] = retval = []
        return retval
```

Then use it to accumulate the results:

```
dict1 = OrderedMultidict()
for k, v in list1:
    dict1[k].append(v)
```

This approach removes the ordering dependency of option 1, in exchange for adding repeated lookups of each key (though only the first lookup invokes Python level code in `__missing__`; after that, if `OrderedDict` is C level as in modern Python 3 code, the lookups will remain C level as well). That said, while repeated lookups are theoretically somewhat worse than writing each key exactly once, in practice I suspect this solution will be faster on modern CPython (where `OrderedDict` is a C built-in); on Python 2 and older Python 3, where it's implemented in Python (while `groupby` is always C level), `groupby` is more likely to win, but when both types are C accelerated, `groupby` actually has some additional overhead that may make it lose.